# Facing the issue of native libraries when compiling project in Android N

Tags: android, pjsip, csip-simple, android-native-library

I am using the project [CSipSimple](https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple) as a reference in my current project.

Project works fine until i have not tested it in the Android N.

I am getting strange errors when m running my project in Android N.

[image]

I have done some googling for that and came to know that by changing the complile SDK version for project will help me to get rid of this error but that thing wont help me in my case.

So any other workaround for this ?

It would be grateful to suggest any changes/guidelines to avoid this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before API 23, this error `Text Relocations` was given as warning, so it does not cause problems. From API 23 it was thrown as error. The `.so` file with text relocation may have memory leaks. So it must be fixed and recompiled with latest Android NDK.

Quick fix will be to set `tagetApiVersion` to `22` in `build.gradle` file.